# Prove $\left|\exp(z)-(1+\frac{z}{n})^n\right| \leq \frac{|z|^2}{n} \exp(|z|) + \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}\right|$.

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that

$$\left|\exp(z)-(1+\frac{z}{n})^n\right| \leq \frac{|z|^2}{n} \exp(|z|) + \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}\right|$$

How can one prove that? I tried using induction, but I think it's the wrong approach.

Comment: Seems to be a Taylor expansion.